# How to download the file from online azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

When I tried to download the image file from the online azure blob, it throws exception as "The given path's format is not supported". My code block is below:

```
StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);
CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
container = client.GetContainerReference(blobName);


CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(MyPath);
await blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(Path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);


using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Path))
{
    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
}
```

If I provide the local path as "c:\users\Joy\Downloads" in path,as like below:

```
var localPath = @"C:\Users\Joy \Downloads\user.jpg" ;
await blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(localPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(localPath))
{
    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
}
```

It can be copied into corresponding location. But I couldn't download the file in my custom location.

Comment: What's your value of "Path" variable? It's supposed to be a local file path.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I enabled [public read access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources) to my blobs to check this issue. I created a console application and you could refer to the following code snippet for downloading the file and maintain the virtual directory in your local file system as follows:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://brucchstorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/2017/11/28/lake.jpeg"));
var localPath = Path.Combine(/*your custom root folder for storing file(s)*/AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,$"downloads\\{blockBlob.Name}"); //blockBlob.Name =2017/11/28/lake.jpeg
var rootDir = new FileInfo(localPath).Directory;
if (!rootDir.Exists) //make sure the parent directory exists
    rootDir.Create();

await blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(localPath,FileMode.Create);

//OR

using (var fs = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fs);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Moreover, you could construct the `CloudBlockBlob` instance with the Uri contains the SAS token as follows:

```
https://brucchstorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/2017/11/28/lake.jpeg?st=2017-11-28T06%3A28%3A00Z&se=2017-11-29T06%3A28%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=15NAaRB43C%2BniIZZe8gAvFl7LY%2BS6K7DNyjLflpvgBg%3D
```

More details, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2).